# R ggplot convert geom_raster to bubble plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

A newbie here. 
I have plotted a chart using `geom_raster` as given below(`data.frame` created just for illustration):

```
require(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# Create the data frame.
sales_data <- data.frame(
  emp_name = rep(c("Sam", "Dave", "John", "Harry", "Clark", "Kent", "Kenneth", "Richard", "Clement", "Toby", "Jonathan"), times = 3), 
  month = as.factor(rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan"), times = 3)),
  dept_name = as.factor(rep(c("Production", "Services", "Support", "Support", "Services", "Production", "Production", "Support", "Support", "Support", "Production"), times = 3)), 
  revenue = rep(c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 500), times = 3),
  status = rep(c("Low", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "Very High", "Very High", "Very High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Low"), times = 3)
)

sales_data$month <- factor(sales_data$month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))
month_vector <- levels(sales_data$month)
number_of_enteries <- nrow(sales_data)

sales_data$status <- factor(sales_data$status, levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"))
sales_data$month <- as.integer(sales_data$month)

ggplot(sales_data, aes(x = month, y = dept_name)) +
  geom_raster(data = expand.grid(sales_data$month, sales_data$dept_name),
              aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, width=1, height=1), fill = NA, col = 'gray50', lty = 1) + #default width and height is 1
  #SAFE: geom_point(aes(size = revenue, col = revenue), 
  #           shape = 16, position = position_jitter(seed = 0), show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(aes(size = status, colour = cut(revenue, c(-Inf, 199, 301, Inf)) ), 
             shape = 16, position = position_jitter(seed = 0), show.legend = F) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "revenue", 
                     values = c("(-Inf,199]" = "red",
                                "(199,301]" = "#ffbf00", #amber
                                "(301, Inf]" = "green") ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = revenue), size=4, vjust = 1.6, position = position_jitter(seed = 0)) + #try with geom_text

  #geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.5, xmax = 3.5, ymin = -1, ymax = 0.5), fill = "grey", alpha = 0.03)+
  #annotate("text", x=0.5, y=-1, label= "Chart title", fontface =2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid = element_blank(),

    axis.text = element_text(colour = "blue", face = "plain", size =11)
  ) +
  #coord_polar(start = 0.5, clip = 'off') +

  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.5,3.5), expand = c(0,0), breaks = 1:length(month_vector), labels = month_vector) +

  # Remove extra whitespace from y-axis so lines are against the axis
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  # Add straight lines at each factor level, shifted left/down so they're between values
  geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(sales_data$dept_name) + 0.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(sales_data$month) - 0.5, color = "grey")
```

Output Plot: 
[image]

Above given plot is exactly appearing how I want, but only difficulty is, `geom_raster` doesn't support `ggplotly` tooltip on mouseover. Also, few other overlapping of `geom_points` in case of larger dataset.

That is why, I want to use bubble plot instead of `geom_raster`. But I am unable to get, how it can be done ? How, I can categorize data in grid format in single plot. ?

Also, is there any way I can put bubbles in more organized way inside a square tile instead of randomly (jittering) plotting which leads to overlapping sometimes.

I am sure there are ways to achieve same result without `geom_raster`. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with ggplot, you can customize it. Unfortunately I don't know a workaround for `geom_jitter()`.

```
sales_data <- data.frame(
  emp_name = rep(c("Sam", "Dave", "John", "Harry", "Clark", "Kent", "Kenneth", "Richard", "Clement", "Toby", "Jonathan"), times = 3), 
  month = as.factor(rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan"), times = 3)),
  dept_name = as.factor(rep(c("Production", "Services", "Support", "Support", "Services", "Production", "Production", "Support", "Support", "Support", "Production"), times = 3)), 
  revenue = rep(c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 500), times = 3),
  status = rep(c("Low", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "Very High", "Very High", "Very High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Low"), times = 3)
)

sales_data$status <- factor(sales_data$status, levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"),ordered = T)
sales_data$month <- factor(sales_data$month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), ordered = T)


plot = sales_data%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = dept_name, label = emp_name))+
  geom_jitter(aes(color = revenue),width = 0.3, height = 0.3)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(1.5,2.5))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(1.5,2.5))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Department Name")


plotly::ggplotly(plot)
```

Here we first plot the points, then add our own lines using `geom_vline` and `geom_hline`. Then we modify the background.